# Error converting app from Bluemix SSO service to AppID service

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-appid

I'm having an issue converting my application from IBM Bluemix's SSO service to their AppID service. I performed all of the steps at `https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2018/04/converting-applications-ibm-single-sign-service-ibm-cloud-app-id/` but when I try to log in I get this message instead of a login screen: `Cannot GET /oauth/v3/c38ad436-9807-4747-bebe-fc2fe5b1ae82`. Anyone know what could be causing this?

Comment: What is the url in the address bar of the browser when you see this error?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a misconfiguration. The URL you pasted should have `/authorization` at the end, like `/oauth/v3/c38ad436-9807-4747-bebe-fc2fe5b1ae82/authorization`.

If you can paste your code/config it would be easier to tell you where the issue is.

You can also watch App ID video tutorials that explain how to instrument different types of applications - https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLbAYXkuqwrX2WLQqR0LUtjT77d4hisvfK